# How can I edit and transfer output tables from R?

Tags: r, output, visualization

I am working with R for analyzing data for my research paper. I have run some regressions and marginal effects and would like to get the output in a format that I can include in my research paper (best would be tables as images). How can I do this?

I have tried using the sumtable() command, but it only provides a table that summarizes the overall data that I am using and not the specific regressions or the marginal effect output.
I have also used htmlreg() but as far as I know it is only for regressions, and I do not know how to transfer the html output into my word document where I am writing the paper.

Comment: you can open html tables in excel, format, and copy into word

Comment: Try stargazer. Will give latex and text output. You can select the images once you compile them as pdf .!

Comment: (1) Bring up the html file in your browser and press ctrl-A ctrl-C to copy it to clipboard and then right click on the insert point in Word and choose whatever paste option you want. (2) If there are images use this second method. Convert HTML to Word, by installing pandoc (https://pandoc.org/installing.html ) and from  cmd line create Word file using `pandoc my.html -o my.docx` .  Now on main Word document click on desired insert point and on the Insert tab in the Text area click on Object, choose Create from File tab, click on Browse and browse to file and click OK.

Comment: The `modelsummary` package has functions to summarize regression models and also various descriptive data summaries. You'll find many tutorials on the website (disclaimer: I am the author): https://vincentarelbundock.github.io/modelsummary/